# Unexpected output from list.append()

Tags: python

I am puzzled:

```
class lin_reg:

     def __init__(self):
    ''' Executes the program '''

    Indep_Array, Dep_Array = self.Prob_Def()
    Total_Array = Indep_Array.append(Dep_Array)
    print Indep_Array, Dep_Array, Total_Array
    NumArray = len(Total_Array)

def Prob_Def(self):

    Analy_Type = raw_input('Type of Regression(linear-n,nonlinear-nl): ')
    Num_IndepVar = eval(raw_input('Number of Independent Variables: '))
    Indep_Array = []
    for IndepVar in range(Num_IndepVar):
        ArrayInput = eval(raw_input('Enter the array: '))
        Indep_Array.append(ArrayInput)
    Dep_Array = eval(raw_input('Enter the dependent array: '))
    return Indep_Array, Dep_Array
```

When I run this code, I get output as follows:

```
obs=lin_reg.lin_reg()
Type of Regression(linear-n,nonlinear-nl): nl
Number of Independent Variables: 3
Enter the array: [1,2,3]
Enter the array: [2,3,4]
Enter the array: [3,4,5]
Enter the dependent array: [5,6,7]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]] [5, 6, 7] None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    obs=lin_reg.lin_reg()
  File "C:\Python27\DataAnalysis\lin_reg.py", line 13, in __init__
    NumArray=len(Total_Array)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

How is the dependent array `Dep_Array` automatically appended to `Indep_Array` and why is `Total_Array` returning `None`?

I was expecting to see output like this for above input:
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]] [5,6,7] [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]

Comment: I looked into the duplicate. However, if I had stumbled into your "so-called duplicate" before I had posted this question, I would have still posted it. May be it is just me but I think I would not have been able to solve my problem like here by referring to the "duplicate".

Comment: What you're seeing is that `Total_Array` has a value of `None`. It gets that value from the assignment `Total_Array = Indep_Array.append(Dep_Array)`. The other question's answers explain that, and why, this will result in `Total_Array` ending up with a value of `None`. I don't really see how this could fail to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.append` modifies the original list and returns `None`. You want `+`.

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your code to how Python should look.

```
class lin_reg(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.indep, self.dep = self.initialise_from_user()
         self.total = self.indep + self.dep
         print self.indep, self.dep, self.total
         self.n = len(self.total)

def initialise_from_user(self):
    analysis_type = raw_input('Type of Regression(linear-n,nonlinear-nl): ')
    n = int(raw_input('Number of Independent Variables: '))

    indep = [np.matrix(raw_input('Enter the array: ')) for _ in range(self.n)]
    dep =  np.matrix(raw_input('Enter the dependent array: '))

    return indep, dep
```

Comment: How many people have been burned by trying to assign the output of a mutating function? It's happened to me too.

Comment: @MarkRansom but it's an easy bug to catch, unlike nasty things that happen halfway through a chain of such functions.

Comment: @katrielalex: In the code you modified, do you mean to import numpy as np?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades yes. You probably want to make `indep` an `np.array` as well, but you can work out how to do that =) Also edited slightly

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason that `Dep_Array` is automatically appended to `Indep_Array` is because `Indep_Array.append(Dep_Array)` modifies `Indep_Array`.
2. The function `append` returns `None` instead of a list. This was done on purpose to prevent people from chaining functions that modify the arguments, such as `a.append(b).remove(c).doSomething(d)`. By preventing this, the code remains clear and easier to understand for someone unfamiliar with those methods.

Comment: +1 for showing problems with append on chaining..

Answer (score 1):

It's because `list.append()` doesn't return anything, it changes the list in place. Therefore,

```
 Total_Array=Indep_Array.append(Dep_Array)
```

makes `Total_Array` equal `None`.

Also, naming conventions are against capitalized variable names.

Comment: +1 for taking my thoughts to the naming conventions. Are there any guideline (short one) to have cursory look?

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) might help.